# Rotate ruler on map?

Tags: javascript, html, image, rotation

Hi here is the full code. For now the ruler just follows the mouse, fine.
I want to rotate the ruler on the page whereever it is

by pushing button like "W" for anticlockwise"S" for clockwise

or

by a help of a slider bar

https://paste.to/en/view/5ef5e5618b590

Comment: Please add your code to the post, and explain what goes wrong with it.

Comment: stackowerflow site did not allow me to send a post with whole code, so i gave paste.to link to see source. I just need an update of the code to handle rotation issue. It is downloadable in html